# QT QML - Display a Rect in existing ApplicationWindow from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have Qt Project (Windows, Desktop) along with several QMl files. My **main.cpp** looks like this (simplified):

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
       QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
       QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

       QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
       engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/QMLFiles/main.qml")));

       return app.exec();
    }
```

The **main.qml** is this:

```
    import QtQuick 2.7
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
    import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
    import QtQuick.Window 2.0

    ApplicationWindow {
       id: mainWindow
       objectName: "mainWindow"
       visibility: "Maximized"
       title: "Title goes here"
    }
```

I also have some qml files (**window.qml**) that i want to display in the Apllication Window. They behave like windows (dragable, resizeable, ...).

```
    import QtQuick 2.7
    import QtQuick.Window 2.0
    //Removed MouseAreas and children
    Rectangle {
       id: rect
       objectName: "rect"
       width: 400
       height: 400
       x: 100
       y: 100
       border.width: 2
       border.color: "black"
   }
```

I can of course call them in the **main.qml** file with

```
    import QtQuick 2.7
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
    import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
    import QtQuick.Window 2.0

    ApplicationWindow {
       id: mainWindow
       objectName: "mainWindow"
       visibility: "Maximized"
       title: "Title goes here"
       //New:
       Window {}
    }
```

But I don't want them to be there from the start. I want a HandlerObject (or something) in C++ that manages a list of Windows generated by the window.qml file and can open and close them with a function. Is this possible?

Cheers

Comment: Read [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html) article carefully.

Comment: I did but I can't seem to find something that works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to have a C++ data set per Window, my suggestion would be to implement a `QAbstractListModel` derived class that provides this data, each "row" of the model having the data for one Window.

```
class WindowModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

// ....
};
```

Exposing an instance of that model to QML

```
WindowModel windowModel;
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("_windowModel", &windowModel);
engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/QMLFiles/main.qml")));
```

On the QML side you then use a `Repeater` with the `Window` as its `delegate` and the C++ provided model as its `model`.

```
Repeater {
    model: _windowModel
    delegate: Window {
        // access data provided by the model
    }
}
```